# How to detect underflow in a CSS region

Tags: javascript, css

When flowing text into multiple regions, the javascript property regionOverset returns "overset" if text will overflow into a subsequent region (if any) and returns "fit" if the text will not overflow the region (but may not fill it completely)
How can I detect if the last region has **not** been completely filled ? 
Imagine a style sheet like

```
.flow-source {-webkit-flow-into: flow;  -ms-flow-into: flow;}
.flow-container {-ms-flow-from: flow; -webkit-flow-from: flow;}
 #Leg1     {width: 8rem; height: 22rem;}
```

and HTML content like

```
<div class="flow-source" id="content" align="justify"> ...text here... </div>
<div class=flow-container id=Leg1></div>
```

Then regionOverset returns "fit" even if the text only takes up a fraction of the region. I considered changing the region to have a max-height rather than height, but how can I retrieve the max-height to compare with the offsetHeight property of the div ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
var element = document.getElementById('idhere');
var maxHeight = element.style.maxHeight;
```

Comment: sounds right, but element.style.maxHeight is returning empty string

Answer (score 1):

The answer I eventually found was

```
       var element = document.getElementById("Leg1");
       var style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
       var maxHeight = style.getPropertyValue("max-height");
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, according to the documentation I found,

> **overset** indicates the region is the last in the chain, and does not have enough room to display remaining content.

Sounds like `overset` is indeed the value you want.

See http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/css-regions/Region/regionOverset.
See also http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/css-regions/NamedFlow/firstEmptyRegionIndex

Comment: no, I'm looking for underset where the content does NOT fill the last region